# Questions using my site as the basis are unfairly being closed

Tags: discussion, support, questions, close-reasons

I've posted two questions now. Very specific ones at that. They were being answered by people who understood the question and doing so with reasonable and helpful answers.

Yet I see this message over and over again:

> closed as **not a real question** by spender, CMS, Gaby, gnovice, Jonathan Sampson♦ 56 mins ago
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

It's driving me nuts!

Now, if you want to close and/or delete this question for being so in your face that you can smell the back of my head, that's fairly reasonable.

But I find it insincere for you to keep closing questions I ask about my website.

Is that vague? No, it's not.

I wanted an overall general opinion on the design of my website. I didn't want only opinions on my clock script or my window script. I wanted opinions about the entire thing. So why would I write it any other way?

Stop closing my posts, gods dammit! I was getting lots of feedback. Now I'm not thanks to it being closed.

Comment: This is not a site for asking people to give their opinions on your web page design. This is a site for asking specific *programming-related* questions. Your questions were too open-ended and subjective. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: -_- my question was 100% completely related to PRGORAMMING. It was a discussion about the PROGRAMMING of my web site. As it happens that my web site was PROGRAMMED and I asked for suggestions on how to make it better. I was looking for constructive critisim so that I might be able to make it better.

Comment: And guess what to make a web site better you need to PROGRAM it... or change some graphics in photoshop... but meh either way sorry for including graphical questions aswell its horrible isnt it

Comment: Now my entire web site was a AJAX experiment... if you had looked at the web site you may have realised this and notice the entire thing was about programming skills

Comment: Now tell me how this is not good enough?

Comment: @MrEnder: it's not good enough by definition.  Read the FAQ.  Trust me on this.  It's worth it.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Original message before migration, for anyone interested: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bdfbc93b-0ea5-4d0f-9a9d-46dfe67a1f57/view-source

Comment: @mrender: You can associate your accounts - user profile - accounts tab.

Answer (score 13):

Your questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441582/web-page-opinions-and-suggestions-closed) & [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443988/looking-for-opinions-and-sugestions-on-my-website-general-question-closed) are not questions. You are asking for opinions about how to improve your site. Thats not how SO operates. You present the community with a question that requires a definitive answer.

For example:
How can I make widgetA work on my website. I am using this technology. Here is what I've tried so far.

This presents a real question. You need to figure out what you want to do to improve your web site. Another recommendation might be to promote yourself with a little more professionalism. This is not a forum, it is a question and answer community. Be respectful of the community and you will be respected.

Comment: I was highly professional till someone closed my post... TWICE... also I don't know where I can improve my code hence why I asked a general question and I got back amazing input. Well since I can ask for opinions on this web site to further my progression on learning. This site just lost a customer. I find it highly frustrating and immature.

Comment: take it to refactormycode.com mrender... stackoverflow is not here to offer suggestions and opinions.

Comment: Additionally, SO encourages asking *complete* questions: leaving important aspects of it only referenced in a link that is extremely likely to change (or even die) makes a poor question, and I'd either edit the question to include that code or vote to close it.

Comment: "This site just lost a customer." A customer? What were you buying?

Answer (score 10):

In a comment on [dboarmann's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42259/questions-using-my-site-as-the-basis-are-unfairly-being-closed/42264#42264):

> I was highly professional till someone closed my post

You were civil, which is certainly to be commended. We do occasionally get users who are not.

Alas, your first "question" was presented in a stream of conscienceness style. Unfair though it may be that suggests an undisciplined (read 'not very professional') approach. We are comfortable with casual here, but this is a site for technical questions and precision is generally regarded as a good thing.

The writing on your second question was better, but we expect and encourage appeals to be managed by editing the original rather than reposting.

Finally, Stack Overflow is for questions that have answers, and your requests do not fit well in that mold.

All that said, *please do not be unduly discouraged*. You are not on any list of bad users, and you have not made any unrepairable mistakes. **You are welcome in this community.** Spend a little time scoping out the culture of the sites and reading the FAQ and learning how things work around here, and hopefully the rest of your time with us will be more fulfilling.