# Does criticizing downvoting automatically attract downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Has any question or answer in Meta Stack Overflow criticising downvoting in any way, shape or form escaped being downvoted itself?

[Even Jeff Atwood isn't immune.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting)

Have there been *any* exceptions?

Comment: Nobody likes a whiner... ;-)

Comment: I wasn't criticizing the concept of downvotes so much as I am criticizing unbalanced, extreme forms of downvoting. I am all for downvotes, in proper moderation. For all but 6 out of 100k+ users it isn't an issue.

Comment: only from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1782/downvoter

Comment: @Jeff - and yet you got downvoted.

Comment: well presumably there's a certain knee-jerkiness to downvoting for hilarity, particularly when it is me doing the talking about downvoting. I don't usually mind, but I do mind when it prevents discussion of the topic -- the post was forced off the homepage before reasonable discussion could happen.

Comment: @Jeff - Given that this is a discussion site, I'd say your question is a good example of why that -5 limit should probably be changed to -10 or more for meta.

Comment: I'm going to leave it open for a few more days to see which answer gets the least downvotes.

Comment: @Andrew: FWIW, the discussions on that linked question of Jeff's had considerable disagreement on the proposal, and downvotes on meta often mean "I disagree" rather than "not useful" as on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it does.  Watch this:

**Downvoting sucks!**

Comment: Hey!  Who's the wise-ass who upvoted me?

Comment: I would downvote the hell out of this but my rep dropped to 0 the last time I said downvoting sucks and I still havent recovered.

Comment: I'd downvote your comment if I could...

Comment: @Andrew you can just find another answer of mine and downvote that.  At least thats what most people here do.

Comment: Strangely enough, these questions and answers don't seem to have attracted much downvoting. (I'm going to jinx things by saying that, but still...)

Answer (score 7):

Never gonna give you up, never gonna vote you down, never gonna lower your rep, and hurt you!

Comment: This doesn't call for downvoting ... it calls for the instant and permanent banning of the user!

Comment: Be glad I didn't adapt the whole thing.  "We're no strangers to downvoting...  You have a vote, and so do I!..."

Comment: This will soon become one of they many memes of meta. To be know as StackRolling.

Comment: Cultural note: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling

Comment: You wouldn't get this from any other site.

Comment: Aaaand I got my first downvote on this post today over 5 years later. Oh the irony!

Comment: I linked to this question from a hot Meta Stack Overflow question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308448/38765