# What is Stackoverflow's back story?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've only recently come to discover and appreciate SO and related sites - they are an order of magnitude better than experts-exchange and the like.

I create and launch lots of hobby sites so I was really interested in knowing SO's story, how did it come about, and how was it so successful?  What lessons can I learn to make my own site launches more successful?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him

Comment: See here for more recent news: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/vote-count-is-off-and-why-jeff-is-trying-to-destroy-all-bacon

Answer (score 3):

See here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com

You have the entire history from the first post till the last

Comment: that's.. a lot of reading. And don't forget the podcasts! http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html

Comment: +1 to Mr Atwood's response! Now I have some listening material to keep me entertained/asleep on my trip to London!

Comment: Were there some pre-blog.SO discussions on joelonsoftware.com and codinghorror.com also?  I vaguely remember Jeff starting to talk about the SO project back in 2008ish.

Comment: First reference: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/choosing-your-own-adventure.html " I have a little micro-ISV startup opportunity I'll be working on, a web property I'm building out with one of the above people. I'm not ready to announce the details yet, but when I do, you'll read about it here."

Comment: More concrete details: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html

Comment: @Downvoter: I was bored (on a conference call) so I recalculated your rep as requested.

Comment: Thanks @bill, now you can vote on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50560/allow-10k-users-to-recalculate-their-own-rep

Answer (score 3):

After a botched experiment, Stackoverflow found itself lost, travelling through time. Leaping from one life to the next, Stackoverflow must try to set wrong things right - each time hoping its next leap will be the leap home.

Is that what you meant by back story?

Comment: Oh boy! Yeah exactly like that....

Comment: Wait a second... I thought Stack Overflow was a crack commando unit sent to prison by a military court for a crime they didn't commit.

Comment: @Bill at least it's not an alien that crash landed on earth living with a normal American family while constantly trying to eats its pet cat.