# What metric is used to weight the rarity of the badges awarded on SO?

Tags: discussion, badges

Here are the explanations:

> Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an accomplishment!

> Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested.

> Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of Stack Overflow. They are easy to earn.

The statistics don't really agree with that for many of the badges; for example, **Booster**, **Epic**, **Generalist**, and **Outspoken** are all awarded more rarely than the average gold badges.  **Booster**, in particular, is rarer than *all* of the gold badges, except for the 'gold' version of essentially the same thing (**Publicist**).  The biggest WTF is the that the rarest badge is a bronze one, **Precognitive**, that has never been awarded and I guess never will (is there any point in it existing if it can't be awarded?).

So, am I looking too deeply into this? Were they just made up by someone, when the site was being designed?

Comment: I think `Precognitive` has meaning outside SO. On SO it is basically an easter egg.

Comment: Ah, I get it ..  it's to promote Area 51, and possibly to discourage people from trying to 'collect' all the badges  :D

Answer (score 2):

Using the Precognitive badge as example of a difficult to obtain bronze badge is not correct; the description for the badge is the following:

> Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase

As Stack Overflow has not been created from a proposal, nobody can have that badge. It is reported for Stack Overflow because, I think, the list of badge cannot be personalized for a specific Q&A site; the only exception is Area 51 for which there are badges specific for that site. That is also the reason why Area 51 didn't have a Super-Collider Drop-down Menu: the site is using custom code, and integrating features that are available in other sites is a little more difficult for the fact there is code that needs not to be changed, on Area 51.

Golden badges are more difficult to obtain that other badges:

- Legendary requires your reputation increased by 200, 150 times
- Great Answer requires that your answer has been up-voted from at least 100 users
- Publicist requires that you shared a link that has been visited from 1000 different IPs in 5 days

The difficulty of obtaining a badge, and the distribution of the badges are not correlated. Golden badges normally require more time, to get them; the distribution of the badges depends from how long the users have been using the SE site.

Comment: "The difficulty of obtaining a badge, and the distribution of the badges are not correlated" <-- I get what you're trying to say (e.g. learning to walk is very "difficult", even though a lot of people have successfully done it), but it's still something that appears to be a statistical impossibility.  Gold badges should be rarer than silver badges, and they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I think partly it is how hard it is to preplan and do the work to get a badge.  Most of my gold badges I have got due having asked good questions on the site a long time ago.   I could not have planned any of these questions to give me a gold badge.

However if someone wishes to get the Generalist badge, it is easy to see how they could preplan a method of getting it in well under one year.

Comment: We can preplan to vote 40 times daily to get the Electorate badge which will take only 15 days, edit posts non-stop for the Copy-Editor badge which can take as few as 5 days, etc.

Comment: Yes the Elactorate badge is easy to get and often results in suboptimal behaviour with people voting up questions that "should" not be voted on.   (down votes are limited)

Comment: Downvotes are limited?

Comment: @AnnZen there is a rule (Sorry can't remember details) that stops a person who mostly down votes from doing a great number of down votes.

Comment: I've seen profiles which does **far** more downvoting than upvoting. There's nothing wrong.

Comment: @AnnZen.I expect most people will never hit the rule, but if someone voted on the first 40 question they see on the home page each day without doing other voting.....

Comment: Down and up votes have the same limit. The complexity arises from votes on *questions* being given a higher limit in a non-intuitive way. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes (the other notes there are also interesting... Especially: if you can manage to vote on stuff that gets deleted within a day, you can have effectively unlimited votes!)

Comment: @Shog9 for some reason I convinced there was a rule to limit down votes, was it removed at some point?

Comment: It's been proposed many times. Perhaps most notably: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting