# Badges for using Stack Exchange apps

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I would like to see a badge (or, better, badges) for signing in to a Stack Exchange site with one of the native apps.

These would be bronze badges, and can only be awarded once per site. I'd expect they would be "Participation" badges.

- Green Robot
- Apple Fan

(These are probably the worst badge names ever, but we need to start somewhere.)

I would think that signing in to a site once with the native app would be enough to award the badge, but perhaps a criteria akin to "Enthusiast" could be used (i.e., "visit 30 consecutive days by app").

Comment: I seem to remember there were hats for this as well last year?? Am I right...?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261668/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-reward-some-reputation-points-for-installing-mobile-a), of course. @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I think you're right.

Comment: Not against this, but am wondering "why". Badges are to encourage things, reviewing/voting etc. So not convinced it's good for the site just because people use the app(s). Also, wouldn't we be rewarding people just for (essentially) coming to the site? So defo would need to be some criteria as you suggested (used app for 30 days consecutive - per site) even then I'm not sure of the benefits for the site or other users.

Comment: Isn't this in the winterbash?

Comment: @James: Badges are also to teach people about features of the site. Encouraging people to try out the native apps seems to fit in with that idea.