# What happened to the rule that one can only downvote posts in a 2:1 ratio with their upvotes?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

In March 2010, Stack Exchange [announced major changes to reputation and voting rules](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/19/important-reputation-rule-changes/), most notably, that upvotes on questions would be devalued to 5 reputation (a change that was later reverted). However, the blog post also announced another change to votes:

> Item the second: **after casting 300 votes, you cannot downvote non community wiki posts at more than a 2:1 ratio**.

It doesn't seem like this rule still exists, though, as [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1247892) shows that there are a large number of users who've cast 300 or more votes, with downvote to upvote ratios *much* higher than 2:1. In particular, the first user in the list has downvoted 20,403 posts while having only upvoted two posts, and has registered their account long after the blog post was published. I *highly doubt* that their ratio, and those of others in the list, were caused by downvoting almost-exclusively community wiki posts.

Searching through the blog and through meta posts, there doesn't appear to be any announcement that this rule was removed.

Was this rule never implemented? If it was implemented, when and why was it removed?

(I'm not making an opinion on whether this rule should exist or not. I just want to know why it no longer exists.)

Comment: Meh... after all the effort I put in to downvoting homework dumps, I got a ratio of only 13:(   Maybe I can get some upvotes disassociated from my account to improve my score:)

Comment: Joviality apart, that rule would make effective curation impossible as we would be either stuck with bad questions, or upvoting rubbish to downvote sewage, or both:(  Where are we supposed to find upvotable questions from??

Comment: I mean, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62228892/758133 doesn't understand indirection/pointers at all, immediately followed by a Google request for a format specifier and tbe inevitable 'farenheit/celsius 0.0' 5/9 integer arith question.  That's the newest 3 questions on C tag, all rubbish.  There is nothing to upvote, and it's not even 'Homework Sunday' yet:(

Comment: @MartinJames As far as I'm aware, that policy would consider overall *posts*, not questions and answers separately. Upvoting an answer would increase the number of downvotes you could do on questions.

Answer (score 11):

[Should we have a policy about "too much downvoting"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting/42642#42642) (posted on March 17, 2010 by Jeff Atwood, a couple of days before the blog post) was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [in June 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/42601/6) (also by Jeff Atwood), so presumably, if that limit ever existed in the first place, it was probably removed sometime around June 17, 2010.